# Bootcamp/Parallels - how to use the the line-out on my MacPro

Tags: audio, bootcamp, windows, mac-pro, parallels-desktop

I have a 2010 MacPro which I'm multi-booting (OS X, Win 7) using Parallels and Bootcamp depending on what I'm doing.

I can't see how to change the audio setting so that the line-out on the back of the 'Pro can be used as the default output. Do I need a new driver or something? I've tried using Windows Update but it tells me I already have the best available driver ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer for you for Boot Camp, but for Parallels you should be able to (if you're in Coherence mode):

1. Click on the **Parallels** menu (Just the Devices menu if you're not in Coherence)
2. Go to the **Devices** → **Sound** → **Input Device** menu
3. Choose Built-in Input device or Line in Input Device depending on what shows up.

Example:
[image]

Comment: D'oh - how did I miss that?!  Great - many thanks!